# Issues with struct

Tags: c

I am trying to call a library function with signature

```
void GPIO_Init(GPIO_InitTypeDef* GPIO_InitStruct)
```

where `GPIO_InitTypeDef` is a `typedef` struct.

I have tried doing the following:

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef NE1 = {
    7, GPIO_Mode_AF, GPIO_Speed_25MHz, GPIO_OType_PP, GPIO_PuPd_UP
};
GPIO_Init(NE1);
```

but I get a compiler error

> error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'GPIO_Init' expected
>   'struct GPIO_InitTypeDef *' but argument is of type 'GPIO_InitTypeDef'

I have also tried using the `struct` keyword:

```
struct GPIO_InitTypeDef NE1 = {
    7, GPIO_Mode_AF, GPIO_Speed_25MHz, GPIO_OType_PP, GPIO_PuPd_UP
};
GPIO_Init(NE1);
```

but them I get the compiler error

> error: storage size of 'NE1' isn't known

What am I doing wrong, and what is the proper way to call `GPIO_Init`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
GPIO_Init (&NE1); // <- Note the '&' indicating pointer-to
```

That function expects a *pointer* to a `GPIO_InitStruct` structure, as indicated with:

```
void GPIO_Init (GPIO_InitTypeDef * GPIO_InitStruct)
//                               ^
//                            pointer
```

But your `NE1` variable is an actual *structure,* so you have to use `&` to get the pointer to it, so you can pass that.

Because you're trying to pass the structure instead of a pointer to a structure, that's what's causing your `incompatible type` error.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this whole confusion comes from me not understanding properly what I am doing. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Randomblue, sure, I've added some extra info that hopefully makes it clearer.